# Calling gamesclient methods from other actvities

Tags: android, google-play-services

I'm implementing a chess turn-based multiplayer app. I have a homescreen and a chessboard activity where the game is actually played.

I've seen the skeletonactivity example app and it only has one activity where everything takes place.

How do I still use the turn based listeners and methods such as `takeTurn` etc while I'm in my chessboard activity playing the game?

EDIT: So the way I've implemented my app is as follows. When you're in the homescreen, you can invite a friend, and once `turnBasedMatchInitiated` is called, my chessboard activity is started so the players can start playing

EDIT: I have decided to make my **GamesClient** `public static` so I can access it from my other activity. My main question now is how to utilise the `takeTurn` method. I just want to move a chesspiece, make that count as my turn, and pass the coordinates of my move to the next player. How can I do that? I have looked at the examples and the developer docs but Im still having a lot of trouble understanding how to use taketurn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling taketurn() should be no problem, so long as you have implemented GameHelper in your main activity, so you can still get a connection to the GoogleApiClient.  Also you will have to implement the Match Update Listener and register it.  Then when you call taketurn() you updated match data will be returned in the listener.  In my experience, match data will always return stale data if it is static and it cannot be used this way.